# Is ti possible to `map` an enum to Binding<Bool> in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Working with `MVVM` in SwifUI. My aim is to have an `enum` state property in the `ViewModel` so the `View` could adjust it self according to the state property. States could be: `idle`, `busy`, `done` and `error`. On `done` I want to navigate to another screen using `NavigationLink`, however the problem is that it is expecting a `Binding<Bool>` and I could not figure out a way to map my enum state to bool.

Here is the simplified code:

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: LoginViewModel

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        ...
        // success state
        NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), isActive: self.$viewModel.state /* <---- some sort of mapping should come here */){ EmptyView() }
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope that I am missing something really basic and it could be easily achieved in an elegant way.

**EDIT:**

Seems like it should be possible with the next method:
`NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), tag: .done, selection: self.$viewModel.viewState, label: { EmptyView() })`

However I get an error and I can't figure out what is wrong: `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<ViewState>' to expected argument type 'Binding<_?>'`

Here is the code:

```
final class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var viewState: ViewState = .idle
  func begin() {
    ..
    self.viewState = .done
    ..
  }
}

struct LoginView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel: LoginViewModel

  @ViewBuilder
  var body: some View {
    ..
    NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), tag: .done, selection: self.$viewModel.viewState, label: { EmptyView() })
    ..
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I was very close. The `ViewState` in the vm should be optional:
`@Published var viewState: ViewState? = .idle`

Comment: Please don't edit the solution in the question, add an answer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an elegant way to map it in the view.
However, in your `LoginViewModel` you can have an @Published variable that gets set when the state is updated.

Here is an example:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldNavigate = false  

    var state: State = .idle {
        didSet {
            self.shouldNavigate = state == .done
        }
    }
}
```

Then change your `NavigationLink` to:

```
NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), isActive: self.$viewModel.shouldNavigate){ EmptyView() }
```

**EDIT:**
You can navigate based on state, or some other enum using a NavigationLink like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), tag: State.done, selection: self.$state){ EmptyView() }
```

And update your vm state definition to:
`@Published var state: State = .idle`

Comment: That's what I implemented so far. With this approach I end-up with multiple boolean flags which I would like to avoid.

Comment: trying this approach just with a VM in between is giving me error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<ViewState>' to expected argument type 'Binding<_?>'` Will update my question.

Comment: Has anyone tried this with multiple Views, where an @EnvironmentObject's state decides which view is to be pushed next?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with transformations is that most of them are uni-directional, and a binding requires that its content is both readable and writable. Thus even if you would extend your enum like

```swift
enum State {
  case idle, busy, done

  var isDone: Bool { self == .done }
}
```

you'd still be unable to bind to `$viewModel.state.isDone` because the property is computed. And making it writable by adding a `set` is not feasible as you'd not want to change the enum value via `isDone`.

However, this doesn't mean that it can't be done. You can define `map` over `Binding`, and fool the system that you have a bidirectional communication:

```swift
extension Binding {
    func map<NewValue>(_ transform: @escaping (Value) -> NewValue) -> Binding<NewValue> {
        Binding<NewValue>(get: { transform(wrappedValue) }, set: { _ in })
    }
}
```

, which you can use it in your navigation link, or wherever you need a boolean binding from the enum one.

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), isActive: $viewModel.state.isDone)
```

One caveat, though, is the fact that the mapped `Binding` has a deceptive API, it says that it can also update values, when in fact it doesn't. However for most of the cases where booleans are used to configure availability, this should be fine. Careful, though to not circulate that `Binding` outside the context, as other consumers of that instance might not be aware of its limitation.

Comment: seems extension is not working. getting `Cannot assign to property: 'xxxx' is a get-only property` xcode13.1

Comment: @Dilan perhaps you're trying to map a readonly property, it's hard to tell what the cause of your problem is without more context, asking a new SO question should be the way to go.

Comment: @Dilan I got the same compilation error. This code above worked for me when I tried:

`NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), isActive: $viewModel.state.map { $0.isDone })
`

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem. Here's what I did:

```
    final class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
      @Published var viewState: ViewState = .idle
      func begin() {
        ..
        self.viewState = .done
        ..
      }
    }
    
    struct LoginView: View {
      @ObservedObject private var viewModel: LoginViewModel
    
      @ViewBuilder
      var body: some View {
        ..
        NavigationLink(destination: HomeFactory().make(), tag: .done, selection: 
Binding<Bool>(get: { viewModel.viewState.isPresentable }, set: { _ in viewModel.viewState = .idle })), label: { EmptyView() })
        ..
      }
```